# How can I force AutoLISP application to wait until application run by startapp will finish his work

Tags: autocad-plugin, autolisp

In my AutoCAD LISP plugin I run external application by `startapp` then need to do some action after external application will be closed. How can I do it? maybe I can substitute startapp by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways of synchronize it:

```
(setq Shell (vlax-get-or-create-object "Wscript.Shell"))            
(setq updater(vlax-invoke-method Shell 'Exec (strcat apppath appname ) ))
(while ( = (vlax-get-property updater 'Status ) 0)  
    (Sleep 1000)
)
(vlax-release-object Shell)
```

or using Command:

```
(command "_Shell" (strcat apppath appname ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD Lisp is executed asynchronously.